# Chrome cursor properties only work on edge of object?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Using: Chrome 18.0.1025.151 on MAC OSX 10.6.8

I'm running into an interesting issue.  When using Chrome the cursor property only changes if you hit the very edge of an DOM object.  For example: in the below usage the cursor will only change to the "move" cursor on the very edge of the image. When its completely over the image it goes back to the pointer?

Any idea whats going on here?

CSS:

```
.handle{cursor:move}
```

Usage:

```
<img alt="Lounge" class="handle" src="SOME URL" />
```

Comment: Works here but not in mac. http://jsfiddle.net/4d6Eh/1/

Comment: Have you tried setting a width/height for the object?

Comment: No, I'll give it a try for the images... but it happens with all DOM objects.  So URLs etc. http://jsfiddle.net/FBeyN/

Comment: Same bug. But on several other macs, it works. Maybe a chrome extension. I'll

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Width
2. Height
3. Block

So:

```
.yourObject {
position: relative;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: block;
cursor: move;
}
```

Comment: Still a no go... also defining the width and height is not really an option with variable length <a> tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug on my Macbook Pro running 10.12.3. It appears to be caused by other programs. When certain programs are open/in certain states, `cursor:` CSS rules will only work on object edges, regardless of browser. Experienced this bug with both Spotify and Intellij IDEA.

Try closing out your programs one by one until it behaves properly.